# BLU Theme after Installation HTTP 500 error

Tags: wordpress, installation, themes

I'm trying to install [this](https://themeforest.net/item/blu-a-beautiful-theme-for-businesses-and-individuals/18217358) theme on my WordPress site.

After uploading the theme and when I activate it the site is down and the navigator tell that there is an HTTP ERROR 500!

Can anyone check it and tell me, please?

Comment: May sound obvious but have you installed WordPress' current 'default' theme, to see if you still get the error?

Comment: for the first time i installed wordpress everything work right but when i upload the BLU theme in wp-content/themes and go to admin panel and click activate blu theme and oops the site do not work and the browser chow  : localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: `HTTP ERROR 500` is a very generic error message.  Firstly, clear your Browser's Cache/Site Cookies and refresh the page.  If the error still persists, remove the `.htaccess` file, to see if this makes a difference.  Obviously, make a back up of it first.  If this fails, then it is likely the error resides within; PHP Coding/Scripts or Folder/File permissions.  In which case, it would be better for you to contact the Theme Author?